# Query performing poorly (nested joins, lateral join) (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a query that is touching four tables. The schema is drew in the following ER model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTSCJ.jpg

I'm trying to write a query to return all the sites that the sum of its file sizes does not exceed the storage limit of the associated plan. In other words, I'd like to know the sites that are able to create new files, once there is storage available yet.

The trick is that a contracted plan can have many sites which can have many files, so once one site exceed the limit, all the sites that share the same contracted plan must be disabled as well.

After many tries, I got the following SQL:

```
SELECT sites
FROM plans AS p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cp.plan_id AS plan_id, cp.id AS contracted_plan_id, array_agg(s.id) AS sites, SUM(total_size) AS total
  FROM contracted_plans AS cp
  INNER JOIN sites AS s ON cp.id = s.contracted_plan_id
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT SUM(size) AS total_size
    FROM files AS f
    WHERE f.site_id = s.id
  ) AS agg ON TRUE
  GROUP BY cp.id, cp.plan_id
) AS total_per_contracted_plan
ON p.id = total_per_contracted_plan.plan_id
WHERE total < p.storage_limit;
```

Currently this SQL seems to be working, but I notice that it's not performing so well.

I've populated the database with about 200k contracted plans, 200k sites (one per contracted plan) and about 3kk files (15 files per site). There are only 5 plans, so I've associated each contracted plan to a random plan.

All the PK and FK have index. I'm using PostgreSQL, latest version.

Performing with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I got this: http://chunk.io/f/01c42c8aba7b414dbd8bff0299fbe84b. It took almost 4s to finish which seems excessive.

How can I improve the performance of the SQL?

Comment: Could you put some sample data together with the expected result? Perhaps a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Wow, this SQLFiddle is new for me. Here we go: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce190/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce190/1).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce190/6/0

```
select distinct site_id
  from (select s.id as site_id,
               p.id as plan_id,
               p.storage_limit,
               sum(f.size) over(partition by s.id) as tot_site
          from sites s
          join files f
            on f.site_id = s.id
          join contracted_plans cp
            on cp.id = s.contracted_plan_id
          join plans p
            on p.id = cp.plan_id) x
 where tot_site < storage_limit
```

Comment: I've tried your example and looks like it performed slower than my current one:

`QUERY PLAN | Execution time: 9745.299 ms`

Comment: @andrielfn please try revised sql, see fiddle